# Choosing a JS MVC Framework with large support for desktop and mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile, model-view-controller, frameworks

We have built an app using Knockout.js and targeting desktop browsers (Chrome, Moz, IE7+) as well as Safari, Android stock browser, Chrome for mobile, stock browsers of BlackBerry 7 and windows phone.

We are experiencing huge performance issues on mobile with knockout, that is why we at rebuilding the app from the ground up with another MVC framework.

I have been looking at angular.js but I can't find any doc on its browser support, and if it is really viable for slow mobiles.

I could go into something minimalist like backbone but it would mean doing more stuff myself, which means taking more time and not necessarily doing it better than with a more complete framework.

Which MVC/MVVM/MV whatever framework/library is suited for such a situation ?
Also, it would be nice if it would fit in a phonegap app, but it is not a priority

Answer (score 0):

I have built a `PhoneGap` app with `AngularJS` and `jQuery Mobile`. I am not particularly impressed with `jQuery Mobile` performance but would recommend `AngualrJS` as a solid platform for `mobile`

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS can certainly be a viable alternative, although it may depend on your specific application -and since you did not describe it in great detail, it is hard to give a definitive answer.http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq will hopefully answer some of your questions regarding browser support and performance. I would also take a look at the [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458436/angular-js-backbone-js-or-which-has-better-performance); it was written 2 years ago, but many of the points and concepts discussed remain valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at  [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch). We've started off our cross-platform journey with Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap. It looked as if it was so great when we started but was kind of sluggish when it comes to performance. So then, we decided to go for native targeting each platforms. We wanted to give a try on Sencha Touch before turning onto native and it really paid off well.

Sencha Touch is far better than JQM and the good thing is that it supports Cordova aka PhoneGap and allows you to follow MVC pattern.

[Sencha's kitchen sink](http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1a/built-examples/kitchensink/index.html)

Comment: Sencha seems to be a very good solution, but -correct me if I am wrong- it can deploy only to mobile or desktop environments, not to browsers